# Caixa de texto sobrescrevendo restante do layout

Tags: suporte

Ao elaborar uma pergunta hoje eu percebi que a barra de ajuda (aquela do lado direto) sobrepõe o restante do layout, inclusive o footer do site.
Isso é normal? Para vermos o site não podemos estar elaborando uma pergunta?

A imagem abaixo descreve melhor o que quero dizer:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A pergunta original é do início 2014 e ainda não resolveram o problema, hehehe. Como assim Gabe? :D